# Laravel redis/memcached cache tags logic

Tags: php, caching, redis, tags, laravel-5.5

Found the following  package and it automatically clicked with me, on using tags.

https://github.com/swayok/alternative-laravel-cache

---

Although everywhere else in the tagging system, this is the default behavior,
in Laravel it is different by default (when using Memcached/Redis).

For example:

```
Cache::tags(['tag1', 'tag2'])->get('tag-test1');
Cache::tags(['tag2', 'tag3'])->get('tag-test1');
Cache::tags(['tag2', 'tag4'])->get('tag-test1');

Cache::tags(['tag2'])->flush();
```

Would expect all of the cache to be purged, as it contains the same tag,
but in Laravel it doesn't hit the cache at all, instead you would need to write another 3 lines to invalidate those same caches.

Why is that?
I mean, Laravel (Taylor) chose this path for a reason, may be performance and stuff, but I'm not sure.

I would like to get a simple/accurate explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/swayok/alternative-laravel-cache
Indeed is the expected behaviour for me. For example, when constructing a page that consists of three products, one category, it will be tagged with those three products and categories. If any of the product changes, cache needed to be flushed. In Laravel, I will need to know all three products and category for me to flush then, which is impossible. Don't understand why Laravel took this approach.